# Multicast packets are not sent if I use an address different from 224.0.0.1

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, multicast

I am using [this code](http://miphol.com/muse/2013/09/ws-discovery-in-c.html) to experiment with multicast.

I have wireshark running on another PC in the LAN and I am trying to see the packets sent over the network.

If packets are sent to the IP address `224.0.0.1` they are correctly received, if I send them to the address `239.255.255.250` they are not.

I have this entry in my routing table

```
224.0.0.0/4 dev eth0.100  src 192.0.0.1
```

I know 192.0.0.1 looks weird, but it is the correct interface address

Do you know why packets are not being sent?

Comment: post the code here not elsewhere.

Comment: the code is not mine, it's the one in the page.

Comment: so ? paste it over here.

Answer (score 0):

The PC that you are attempting to capture the multicast traffic most likely has multicast filtering enabled and has not enabled reception of the 239.255.255.250 group.

Any host device that communicates multicast joins the 224.0.0.1 (All Hosts group) so packets sent to that group pass the filter, but not packets sent to 239.255.255.250.

Multicast filtering is usually implemented in the network interface and received frames that don't pass the filter will be dropped in hardware instead of being passed up to the Kernel driver.  If the frames are not passed to the Kernel, then Wireshark can not capture them.

You can verify the active multicast groups per interface with *netstat*.  I'm assuming you're on a Linux system since you tagged the question with "Linux"

```
netstat -g
```

Multicast groups are joined when a socket enables the [IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) socket option.  In order to join the group on your capturing device, you'll need a program that creates a socket and joins the multicast group using the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP socket option

Answer (score 0):

To add to Joel Cunningham's answer in the case of [`switched LAN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN_switching):

There's nothing listening for multicast on `239.255.255.250`, thus no [`IGMP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) joins are sent out. thus the switch does not propagate these multicast frames to the port where you have the `wireshark(1)`-running PC.

Again, `226.0.0.1` is [`well known`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) and is always joined to by all hosts.